# Struggling to create correct index for simple sorted range query

Tags: mysql, query-performance, database-indexes

In my database, I have a table 'karmalog'. It basically is a log of actions in the system. It contains a few 100ks of rows. I'd like to retrieve the newest 36 of log items, but only those log items that match a series of log type (called 'event').

Here's the query:

```
 SELECT id
FROM karmalog
WHERE event
IN (
'FAV_IMG_ADD', 'FOLLOW', 'COM_POST', 'IMG_VOTE', 'LIST_VOTE', 'JOIN', 'CLASS_UP', 'LIST_CREATE', 'FORUM_REPLY', 'FORUM_CREATE', 'FORUM_SUBSCRIBE', 'IMG_GEO', 'IMG_ADDSPECIE', 'SPECIE_ADDVIDEO', 'EARN_MEDAL'
)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 36
```

This query currently takes between 0.2 - 0.5s. I'd like to get it into the 0.00x range. As the above query retrieves a single column, a single condition, and a single sort parameter, I figured I'd just create a proper index and all will be good. No luck so far. Here's the table definition, stripped from irrelevant fields:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `karmalog`;
CREATE TABLE `karmalog` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `event` enum('EDIT_PROFILE','EDIT_AVATAR','EDIT_EMAIL','EDIT_PASSWORD','FAV_IMG_ADD','FAV_IMG_ADDED','FAV_IMG_REMOVE','FAV_IMG_REMOVED','FOLLOW','FOLLOWED','UNFOLLOW','UNFOLLOWED','COM_POSTED','COM_POST','COM_VOTE','COM_VOTED','IMG_VOTED','IMG_UPLOAD','LIST_CREATE','LIST_DELETE','LIST_ADMINDELETE','LIST_VOTE','LIST_VOTED','IMG_UPD','IMG_RESTORE','IMG_UPD_LIC','IMG_UPD_MOD','IMG_UPD_MODERATED','IMG_VOTE','IMG_VOTED','TAG_FAV_ADD','CLASS_DOWN','CLASS_UP','IMG_DELETE','IMG_ADMINDELETE','IMG_ADMINDELETEFAV','SET_PASSWORD','IMG_RESTORED','IMG_VIEW','FORUM_CREATE','FORUM_DELETE','FORUM_ADMINDELETE','FORUM_REPLY','FORUM_DELETEREPLY','FORUM_ADMINDELETEREPLY','FORUM_SUBSCRIBE','FORUM_UNSUBSCRIBE','TAG_INFO_EDITED','JOIN','IMG_GEO','IMG_ADDSPECIE','IMG_REMOVESPECIE','SPECIE_ADDVIDEO','SPECIE_REMOVEVIDEO','EARN_MEDAL') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `user_sec_id` (`user_sec_id`),
  KEY `image_id` (`object_id`),
  KEY `date_event` (`date_created`,`event`),
  KEY `event` (`event`),
  KEY `date_created` (`date_created`),
  KEY `date_created_2` (`date_created`,`id`),
  KEY `event_2` (`event`,`delete`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `user_sec_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_sec_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As you can see, I've tried a few indices already. Not shown in this version were two other index attempts (id, event and event, id), both to no avail. In all combinations tried so far, MySQL explain keeps saying it is using filesort.

Any ideas?

Comment: I know enums map to ints (or short ints) but I'd try to use numerical values instead. Just in case.

Comment: @leo I'll keep that as a last resort, because trying that would mean rewriting major parts of the application. It's not something I can quickly try.

Comment: I am not sure, but let's suppose you have a list of 30 enums and you want to filter just 10 of them. If you "smartly" associate those 10 to values 0~10, you could query using "in between" clause (or even  < ) , which is possibly even faster than the "in" clause.

Comment: I bet mysql assigns the next enum value sequentially. In this case, just try to declare your enums in the same order you're declaring in your query (I mean, declare those ones used in your WHERE first in the table creation) and let's see if the optimizer is smart enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT id
FROM karmalog
WHERE event IN ('FAV_IMG_ADD', 'FOLLOW', 'COM_POST', 'IMG_VOTE', 'LIST_VOTE', 'JOIN',
                'CLASS_UP', 'LIST_CREATE', 'FORUM_REPLY', 'FORUM_CREATE', 'FORUM_SUBSCRIBE',   
                'IMG_GEO', 'IMG_ADDSPECIE', 'SPECIE_ADDVIDEO', 'EARN_MEDAL'
               )
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 36;
```

The first index to try is `karmalog(event, id)`.  The second is `karmalog(id, event)`.  Neither of these are in your list.

Comment: As the question says "Not shown in this version were two other index attempts (id, event and event, id), both to no avail."